# select dropdown in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

hello every one i am using project table and project modules table 
and i want to make a controller name Task so in this when i add some task it show select drop down menu
i want to fetch all project module in project_module table according to project drop down 
is any one help me out because i don't know ajax an how to use in codeigniter please help me out.

my index page is like this

```
        <?php
        if($list->num_rows > 0){
            ?>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <select onchange="selectprojectmodule(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
                            <option value="-1">Select project</option>
                            <?php
                            foreach($list->result() as $listElement){
                                ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $listElement->id?>"><?php echo $listElement->title?></option>
                                <?php
                            }
                            ?>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <select id="state_dropdown" onchange="selectprojectmodule(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
                            <option value="-1">select project module</option>
                        </select>
                        <span id="state_loader"></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>

                </tr>
            </table>
            <?php
        }else{
            echo 'No Country Name Found';
        }
        ?>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are fetching the project id in onchange() function:

                            select project module

Retrive that value in javascript and pass it in ajax..

```
 function selectprojectmodule(id)
 {
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php",
        data: {'id' : id},
        success: function(result){
        // in result, you will retrieve the project modules..   
        alert(result);
        // here print the result inside html option value..
        }
        });
 }



 index.php: 
 // retrieve that id and pass in mysql query to retrieve the project module list..
 $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
 //your query
 //echo $project_module
```

Comment: i cant understand i am new that code was found some where els can u  plz make a controller and model my data base table is projects and project_module i was fetch projects module from project_module table and projects from projects table